# display tables row according to drop down value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I want to increase or decrease rows of a table by selecting number of rows from drop down

for example if i have select 25 from drop down the table show only first 25 rows only

I want to use this [plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) . but not know how can i use this

this is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/Ez8mL/4/)

```
$('#nrows').change(function(){
    rows = $(this).val();
    alert(rows + ' Number of rows displayed using plugin' );
    $('#table').dataTable();

});
```

please tell me how can i display only selected number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this at initialization, you'd use the `pageLength` [property](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength):

```
$('#nrows').change(function () {
    rows = $(this).val();
    $('#table').dataTable({'pageLength':rows});
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmfax/4/

That being said, that will only work for the first time you initialize the dataTable; after that, you'll want to [update the page length via the API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len%28%29) and redraw the table. If you try to use the above more than once, you'll get an error stating "Cannot reinitialise DataTable" after the second time you toggle the `nrows` dropdown.

Here is a quick & dirty example of initializing the DataTable outside your change handler and then only changing the page length inside of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmfax/6/

I'd honestly recommend against creating your own `nrows` select dropdown though; it's easy enough in DataTables to customize theirs and then you don't have to worry about collisions between the two or overriding their UI.

Comment: @user3713959 Does the answer meet your needs or is there some other requirement?

Comment: this is work fine on `jsfiddle` but not working on my code.I am using bootstrap for table